# xUnit tests with Azure Functions SDK are not working

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, xunit, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to unit test an Azure Functions project, but I ran into this issue : as soon as I install the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions NuGet package, output directory for the DLL is changed to a sub /bin dir and xUnit runner is unable to find the test DLLs anymore.

Here are the steps to reproduce :

1. Create a new solution with a xUnit project only (let's name it "xUnitTests"),
2. Just put a `Assert.True(true);` in the created unit test,
3. Run the test : everything goes smoothly and test is valid,
4. Now add the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions NuGet package and run the test,
5. This time it is ignored...

From what I get from logs is that the build output directory is changed from

`$(SourceDirectory)\xUnitTests\xUnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\`

to

`$(SourceDirectory)\xUnitTests\xUnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\bin\`

So `xUnit.runner.visualstudio` doesn't find the `xUnitTests.dll` as it continues to look after it in the first directory and not in the new .\bin one...

Anybody has an explanation, solution or work around ? (except copying the whole directory to the expected location with an after build event)

Thank you for you help and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now add the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions NuGet package and run the test

AFAIK, you should not add the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package to your `xUnit` project. Instead, follow the below steps.

- You already have an existing Azure Function project.
- Create a  new `xUnit` test project.
- Now add the function project as a reference to your test project.
- Now you can write tests based on your use cases.

Resources :

[Medium](https://medium.com/cheranga/testing-azure-functions-part-2-86e036785f59)

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function)

Comment: Yes, that's it !
My mistake was to add the function project reference AFTER I started adding other dependencies and it was way easier to add the whole Functions SDK instead of importing each external dependencies.
I'm fairly new to this Core 3.1 framework and didn't realized a project dependency would share his. Lesson learned, thank you for your answer !